# Two similar irrational numbers, Coincidence or Correlation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, convergence-divergence, algorithms

I am trying to see if there is any relationship between two values obtained by entirely different means using $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2, \pi, e,$ etc.

In the first equation, I was finding the base of a Kepler Triangle so that the length of the sides equaled the area. That led me to the value $2\sqrt{2+\sqrt5}+2$ [approximately $6.1163420545$].

That value is the base of a right triangle; that same value multiplied by the square root of $\varphi$ is the side $b$; and the same value multiplied by $\varphi$ is the side $c$.

The second equation is simply $\pi^{e/(e-1)},$ which is approximately  $6.1161695807$.

Although this could be (and probably is) completely coincidence, the figures were calculated using Microsoft Excel and are therefore very limited in their accuracy.

So given the uncertainty:

1) Is it possible that these two numbers are actually identical, which would be shown if I were to be using a program that didn't truncate values? (I find this unlikely)

2) Is there any relation between these two values that could provide a clue as to why they are so similar (or is it just complete coincidence)?

Comment: 143 points and no MathJax?

Comment: Give me some time to look it up. It's not a very intuitive process. I would love a general Help file somewhere that provides some suggestions like that..

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: For what it's worth, my calculator gives the same values (to one less decimal place, rounded in the right direction). So I don't think they're two inaccurate versions of one number.

Comment: Where did the expression with $\pi$ and $e$ come from? Just experimentation with them, or some pattern you were investigating?

Comment: @timtfj I was looking for numbers that, when entered into equations, result in themselves such as the phi = phi^2-1. In This instance if I assign the 6.1161695807 value as n, then (n/π)^e=n.

Comment: @kelalaka 100 of the points will be the association bonus, though. Be kind!

Comment: @timtfj I did not downvote, and this is 6th question of the OP.

Comment: I'm thinking that it must be a coincidence, but that how likely you were to get one will depend on how we characterise the set of problems being looked at. For instance it seems surprising that $π^e$ is close to $e^π$ until realise it's the same as $π^{\frac1π}$ being close to $e^{\frac1e}$ and look at the behaviour of $x^{\frac1x}$ near $x=e$.

Comment: Regarding MathJax: now it's been added, there are a few ways you can see what the code is. One is to click a formula to select it then right-click and choose *Show math as TeX commands*. Another is to click *edit* but not bother to edit anything. Another is to click *edited whenever* and look at the edit history (where you can also see what effect the changes had).

Comment: Thank you for the MathJax help!

Comment: You're welcome! : also don't forget you can write the post in a plain text editor then cooy-and-paste—which might make looking up commands at the same time easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two numbers differ at the fourth decimal, so all they have in common is `6.116...`.

Four digits of agreement is something we should expect to arise as a matter or random chance, unless the original expressions are picked from a pool of *possible* expressions with much fewer than 10,000 members.

Your expressions here look complex enough that it's easy to imagine 10,000 other "just as nice" expressions, with different numeric constants or slightly different arithmetic operations or combinations of operations.

Thus is shouldn't be a surprise to find a 4-digit coincidence.

Comment: I think this also depends on the distribution of values for the type of expression that can be produced. $4$ digits coinciding could be taken as some arbitrary number of preceding unwritten zeros also happening to be zero. Most likely the distribution is one that increases the probability of coincidences for small numbers, though.