# Why does Lucas get credit for Fibonacci's progression?

Tags: math-history, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

A so-called "Lucas Number" is, to me, nothing more than a standard Fibonacci progression of $n_2+n_1$ with a different starting point. There are infinitely many similar progressions, so why does Lucas get special credit?

We tend to think of Fibonacci Numbers beginning at $0, 1, 1$ and continuing out by adding the previous two numbers to make the next in line, and Lucas numbers do the exact same thing with the origin of $2$ and $1$.

I would argue that our starting points for both of these values is a misconception, and instead they should begin with the negative values to infinity by adding $n_1$ to the absolute value of $n_2$ e.g. $n_1+\left\lvert n_2\right\rvert$, making a nice mirror of the values left of zero. This allows for $^-1+\left\lvert^-1\right\rvert=0$, $0+\left\lvert^-1\right\rvert=1$, and then the traditional $0+1=1$ and so on for Fibonacci. It also makes Lucas' origin of $2, 1, 3$ make more sense as the progression would look more like $^-3+\left\lvert^-1\right\rvert=^-2$, $^-1+\left\lvert^-2\right\rvert=1$, $^-2+1=^-1$, $1+\left\lvert^-1\right\rvert=2$, $^-1+2=1$, $2+1=3$ and so on.

That being said, why does Lucas get credit for something Fibonacci already discovered when he didn't add anything of value to it? I could as easily begin with $^-2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 9 ...$ does that mean I should get my name attributed to the series?

Can someone please help me understand what's so special about Lucas Numbers that isn't already understood by the Fibonacci sequence?

Thank you!

Comment: Lucas dealt much with primality tests. Maybe this sequence can somehow be used for a primality test (I do not know it however). This could be a reason.

Comment: Dear @mkinson. People have been formatting your posts for you for many years now. Five years ago, someone commented on [one of your questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057992): "$143$ points and no MathJax?". With $143$ updated to $245$, the relevance of that comment has only increased. Please acknowledge all the friendly efforts people have been putting into fixing your posts for you, and learn how to format them yourself. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for that purpose.

Comment: @joriki Yes, you are correct. I didn't really think of the simple arithmetic as needing it, but I suppose that's still laziness on my side. I will strive to improve myself if/when I post in the future.

Comment: @Peter According to Wikipedia, [Lucas sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence#Applications) are indeed used in primality tests (though I don't know if they use specifically the Lucas *numbers*). But it also seems like the Lucas numbers are simply [very closely tied to to the Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number#Relationship_to_Fibonacci_numbers), so it probably wasn't unreasonable to name them after Lucas, who was also seemingly the very first one to give the Fibonacci numbers their name.

Comment: I'm not that knowledgeable about math history which is why I'll only leave comments, but I'd argue that you don't have to name everything after the one who had the idea for a concept, I'd say it's just as fair to give credit to people who earned it by expanding on said concept with their own ideas and efforts.

Comment: As a clarification to my Fibonacci sequence, the progression would be $-3, -2, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3$. I skipped some steps for brevity.

Comment: This is a good question for hsm.stackexchange.com I think. The recently published _The Lucas Sequences_ should contain some answers.

Comment: I think that Lucas progressions are seen as a generalization of the standard Fibonacci progression. (Besides, for me the one and only Lucas sequence starts with 1, 3, 4)

Answer (score 1):

The Fibonacci and Lucas sequences are related to the quadratic equation  $x^2 - Px + Q = 0 $ with $P = 1$ and $Q = -1$. The discriminant is
$D = P^2 - 4Q = 5$ and the roots are $ a = \frac{P+\sqrt{D}}2 = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2\quad\text{and}\quad b = \frac{P-\sqrt{D}}2 = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2$.

The terms of Fibonacci and Lucas sequences can be expressed in terms of the roots $a$ and $b$ as follows

$ F_n = \frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b} = \frac{a^n-b^n}{ \sqrt{D}} = \frac{a^n-b^n}{ \sqrt{5}} $ and

$ L_n = a^n+b^n $.

It follows that $L_0 = 2 \text{ and } L_1 = a + b = P = 1$.

So the values for $L_0$ and $L_1$ are not arbitrary.